# How to to use each in pug with an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

So I have a json file have where I have an array called technologies, I am trying to get a list of the array to be rendered in a pug file like this:

[image: How I want the array data to be rendered in pug]

```
{


            "projects": [
                {
                    "id": "0",
                    "project_name": "A random quote generator",
                    "description": "This is a project that displays a random quote each time the button is clicked or every 5 seconds",
                    "technologies": ["HTML", "CSS", "JAVASCRIPT"],

}
```

This is how I am currently trying to use each in my pug file

```
 ul
           each val in `${projects[id].technologies}`
             li=  val
```

And this is how the data in currently being rendered, which I don't want

[image: Current data output]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using template `${projects[id].technologies}` converts the array `["HTML", "CSS", "JAVASCRIPT"]` to a string, and when you loop throw a string you get letters and not array items

You should use something like this:

```
ul
   each val in projects[id].technologies
        li= val
```